# Word to describe symptoms of illness or pain when someone close to you is sick?

Tags: expressions, terminology

What is it called when you get symptoms of illness or pain when someone close to you is sick? Like a husband gets morning sickness because wife is pregnant.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a *sympathetic* malady.  It comes from the usage of *sympathy* as a common feeling.

Comment: Please add a reference validating this sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Couvade's Syndrome** [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couvade_syndrome) Specific to the expecting father.

> Couvade syndrome, also called sympathetic pregnancy, is a proposed
>   condition in which a partner experiences some of the same symptoms and
>   behavior as an expectant mother.

I do not know of any other *specific terminology* = 'when you get symptoms of illness or pain when someone close to you is sick'.

Answer (score 0):

> It's one type of [**somatoform disorder**](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/somatoform+disorder)
>
> - a group of disorders in which physical symptoms suggesting physical disorders for which there are **no demonstrable organic findings** or known physiologic mechanisms, and for which there is positive evidence, or a strong presumption that the **symptoms are linked to psychological factors**; for example, hysteria, conversion disorder, hypochondriasis, pain disorder, somatization disorder, body dysmorphic disorder, and Briquet syndrome.

Comment: That is a category.  Those mentioned are actual medical disorders with DSM codes and they number > 30 or more. None are in empathy or sympathy to someone else.